# Disable bash tab completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is it possible to disable bash's autocomplete on pressing tab?

The reason I want to do this is that I often paste code from an editor where I use the tab character instead of a number of spaces for indention, into my terminal.

And no, you can't convince me to use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: In zsh, the Tab key inserts a tab if you press it at the beginning of a line (before any non-whitespace character). I don't think bash can be programmed for that (you can bind a key to a bash function, but AFAIK you can't trigger a completion from that bash function).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

put

```
 set disable-completion on
```

string in `~/.inputrc` and  restart your shell. it will disable completion at all.

Comment: not only in bash though...

Comment: To have it only affect Bash, instead of including that line in your `~/.inputrc` file, add this to the appropriate shell startup file: `bind 'set disable-completion on'`

Comment: What Dennis said, and the appropriate startup file is `~/.bashrc` (if it doesn't take in login shells, add `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`).

Comment: `disable-completion` is a readline option, not a bash option. As far as I can check, it does not disable tab completion when copying code to a bash shell.

Answer (score 11):

Dennis' solution

```
bind 'set disable-completion on'
```

can be done on the fly in Bash as well. You do not need to put it in .bashrc.

Musta's solution (bash --noediting) works but also disables command line editing.

Another way is

```
bind -u complete
```

(unset key binding associated with 'complete')

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html,  4.2 Bash Builtin Commands.

Comment: The correct answer for the question "how do I _temporarily_ disable Bash completion?" This helps a lot when you're navigating through a directory with 81,000+ files and you can't even Ctrl+C without waiting two minutes for Bash to come back with a prompt.

Answer (score 7):

To disable Bash tab completion only temporarily you can start a Bash with the `--noediting` option:

```
alias noed='bash --noediting'
```

Answer (score 1):

With terminals supporting [bracketed paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketed-paste) (i.e. most modern terminals) you can run `bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on'` to skip readline handling of the pasted code:

```bash
user@host:~$ bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'
user@host:~$ STR="Foo
> 
Display all 2376 possibilities? (y or n)^C
user@host:~$ bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on' 
user@host:~$ STR="Foo
        Bar"
```