# Disable tab completion in Bash for some directory that contains a large number of files?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm working with large number of files, which I keep in a directory. Every time I go in to that directory and accidentally press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, it takes too long (may be over a minutes) to show files that match the pattern, and I'm quite annoyed with this behavior.

For example, my directory structure is:

```
my-project/
├── docs/
├── data/        <---- contains around 200k files.
└── analyser/
```

Since I still love completion, is there anyway to disable this feature only at the `data/` directory? Like set timeout for 5 sec, or a script that automatically switch off completion when inside specific directory?

Comment: Would you switch to zsh over this? (I don't know if it's possible in bash. I know it's possible in zsh, but it might not be easy, I haven't checked.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but then again bash completion is quite a tricky thing...

The very simplest way is on a per-command basis, it's slightly more flexible than `FIGNORE`, you can do:

```
 complete -f -X "/myproject/data/*" vi
```

This instructs autocomplete that completion for `vi` is for files, and to remove patterns matching the `-X` filter. The downside is that the pattern isn't normalised, so `../data` and variations won't match.

The next best thing might be a custom `PROMPT_COMMAND` function:

```
# associative arrays of non-autocomplete directories
declare -A noacdirs=([/myproject/data]=1 )

function _myprompt {
    [[ -n "${noacdirs[$PWD]}" ]] && {
       echo autocomplete off
       bind 'set disable-completion on'
    } || {
       echo autocomplete on
       bind 'set disable-completion off'
    }
} 

PROMPT_COMMAND=_myprompt
```

This [disables completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29494/disable-bash-tab-completion) (completely) when you are in the directory, *but* it disables it for every path not just files in that directory.

It would be more generally useful to selectively disable this for defined paths, but I believe the only way is to use a default completion function (bash-4.1 and later with `complete -D`) and a lot of messing about.

This *should* work for you, but it *may* have unintended side effects (i.e. changes to the expected completion in some cases):

```
declare -A noacdirs=([/myproject/data]=1 )

_xcomplete() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} # the current token

    name=$(readlink -f "${cur:-./}")  # poor man's path canonify
    dirname=$(dirname "$name/.")

    [[ -n "${noacdirs[$dirname]}" ]] && {
        COMPREPLY=( "" )   # dummy to prevent completion
        return
    }
    # let default kick in
    COMPREPLY=()
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _xcomplete vi
```

This works for completion of `vi`, other commands can be added as needed. It should stop completion for files in the named directories regardless of path or working directory.

I believe the general approach with `complete -D` is to dynamically add completion functions for each command as it is encountered. One might also need to add `complete -E` (completion of command name when input buffer is empty).

---

**Update**
Here's a hybrid version of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` and completion function solutions, it's a little easier to understand and hack I think:

```
declare -A noacdirs=([/myproject/data]=1 [/project2/bigdata]=1)

_xcomplete() {
    local cmd=${COMP_WORDS[0]}
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} # the current token

    [[ -z "$cur" && -n "$nocomplete" ]] && {
        printf "\n(restricted completion for $cmd in $nocomplete)\n"  
        printf "$PS2 $COMP_LINE"
        COMPREPLY=( "" )   # dummy to prevent completion
        return
    }
    COMPREPLY=()       # let default kick in
}

function _myprompt {
    nocomplete=
    # uncomment next line for hard-coded list of directories
    [[ -n "${noacdirs[$PWD]}" ]] && nocomplete=$PWD
    # uncomment next line for per-directory ".noautocomplete"
    # [[ -f ./.noautocomplete ]] && nocomplete=$PWD
    # uncomment next line for size-based guessing of large directories
    # [[ $(stat -c %s .) -gt 512*1024 ]] && nocomplete=$PWD
} 

PROMPT_COMMAND=_myprompt
complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _xcomplete vi cp scp diff
```

This prompt function sets the `nocomplete` variable when you enter one of the configured directories. The modified completion behaviour only kicks in when that variable is non-blank *and* only when you try completing from an empty string, thus allowing completion of partial names (remove the `-z "$cur"` condition to prevent completion altogether). Comment out the  two `printf` lines for silent operation.

Other options include a per-directory `.noautocomplete` flag file that you can `touch` in a directory as needed; and guessing of directory size using GNU `stat`. You can use any or all of those three options.

(The `stat` method *is only a guess*, the reported directory size grows with its contents, it's a "high water mark" that won't usually shrink when files are  deleted without some administrative intervention. It's cheaper than determining the real contents of a potentially large directory. Precise behaviour and increment per file depends on underlying filesystem. I find it a reliable indicator on linux ext2/3/4 systems at least.)

bash adds an extra space even when an empty completion is returned (this only occurs when completing at the end of a line). You can add `-o nospace` to the `complete` command to prevent this.

One remaining niggle is that if you back up the cursor to the start of a token and hit tab, the default completion will kick in again. Consider it a feature ;-)

(Or you could futz around with `${COMP_LINE:$COMP_POINT-1:1}` if you like over-engineering, but I find bash itself fails to set the completion variables reliably when you back up and attempt completion in the middle of a command.)

Answer (score 6):

If your `data` directory contains files with a specific suffix, **e.g.** `.out`, then you can set your `bash` variable `FIGNORE` to `".out"` and these will be ignored. Although it is possible to use directory names too, this does not help on current working directory names.

**Example:**

Create thousands of 100KB test files on physical host with raid 1 HDDs:

```
for i in {1..200000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=102400 count=1 of=file$i.json; done
```

Set the `bash` variable:
`$ FIGNORE=".json"`

Create the test file:
`$ touch test.out`

Test at **5,000** files:

```
$ ls *.json|wc -l
5587
$ vi test.out
```

No delay between the vi and single `tab` before `test.out` appears.

Test at **50,000** files:

```
$ ls *.json|wc -l
51854
$ vi test.out
```

Single tab creates a fraction of a second delay before `test.out` appears.

Test at **200,000** files:

```
$ ls *.json|wc -l
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
$ ls | awk 'BEGIN {count=0} /.*.json/ {count++} END {print count}'
200000
$ vi test.out
```

Delay of 1 second between the vi and single `tab` before `test.out` appears.

**References:**

*Excert from man bash*

```
FIGNORE
              A  colon-separated  list  of  suffixes to ignore when performing filename completion (see READLINE below).  A filename whose suffix matches one of the entries in FIGNORE is
              excluded from the list of matched filenames.  A sample value is ".o:~".
```

Comment: won't help, try create dir w/ about ~100k files. then I do `$ vi <tab><tab>`, it's take lots of time anyway. :\

Comment: still not solve the issue, suppose I have 100k `.json` files, and a single text file named `foo.txt`. turning  `FIGNORE='.json'` on, I type `$ vi <tab>` and still need to wait half a minute so it complete me to `$ vi foo.txt`.
---
real scenario I'm not gonna edit, or mix file types inside that dir, but if I turn on `FIGNORE` and (accidentally) press tab, my keyboard will be freeze for a long time without hint of something like `Display all 188275 possibilities? (y or n)`, which tell me that I can have my keyboard back.

Comment: @neizod - Sorry, I tried many scenarios to get FIGNORE to work on a directory level, to no avail. I guess a custom solution is required, or you simply disable bash completion on that host, or try the zsh solution detailed on our sister site Gilles mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, it's only 1 second on your system, it's around half a minute on my system. So I guess I'd go buy a new PC to make this solution work.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you want (borrowed some code from @mr.spuratic)

Note this doesn't prevent you from pressing TAB using full path (e.g. `vim /directory/contains/lots/files<tab><tab>`

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"
  local NOCOMPLETION=( "/" "/lib" )
  local IS_NOCOMPLETION=0
  for dir in "${NOCOMPLETION[@]}"
  do
    echo $dir
    if [[ $(pwd) == "$dir" ]]
    then
      echo "disable completion"
      bind "set disable-completion on"
      IS_NOCOMPLETION=1
      return
    fi                                                                                                                                                                                              
  done
  if [[ $IS_NOCOMPLETION -eq 0 ]]
  then
    echo "enable completion"
    bind "set disable-completion off"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `pushd`/`popd`. Since this only uses a regular array, not an associative array it will work in bash 3.x too.