# How do you put an upper limit to the bash completion?

Tags: bash

There's a way to [Disable bash tab completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29494/disable-bash-tab-completion?rq=1)

I am looking for a way to just put some sort of upper limit say *1 second* of processing time before stopping the tab completion attempt.  Ideally have it say `at least 3511 possibilities`

Comment: To what commands are you trying to enforce a limit, like your own commands or for `linux` built-ins etc ?

Comment: everything that would come up when you press tab with no input